# “Error”? What error?

Tags: bug

I have tried to submit this question [

In general, given two expressions, $\sqrt{A+B\sqrt{N}}$ and $\sqrt{C+D\sqrt{N}}$, under what conditions is it possible to add or subtract the two so a to yield a third expression, $\sqrt{E+F\sqrt{N}}$. [A, B, C, D, E, F and N are integers, with N not a perfect square]?

] to M.SE. It responds with a message to the effect that the question could not be submitted because of the error stated above (or words to that effect). The problem is that no error has been stated. What gives?

Comment: Screenshot please...

Comment: Radical overflow? (one of the early proposed names for MSE)

Comment: To state the obvious: It's submitting here, so maybe not radical overflow or some other maths error?

Comment: @Geoff It's a pun, not serious speculation on the source of the bug!

Comment: @BillDubuque No worries, I get the pun, that's why I didn't @ you in my comment, but, your mention of it made me think about the MathJax side of things and I thought it was worth pointing out. I know I keep banging on about it, and I promise I won't stop, but PMs would help this site significantly. On most other forums you and I would just PM this part of the conversation as it doesn't really add to the OP.

Comment: @user127096 I do not know how to convey a screenshot to you. I guess I shall just try again. I shall apprise in this space whether I fail again or succeed.

Comment: @user94874 What operating system are you using? Screen shots are generally fairly easy to take with most modern operating systems. Then, you can edit your question and you can click on the image button to upload your screenshot.

Comment: @user127096 Same result. Perhaps you can capture the text of the question and submit it?!

Comment: @Geoff Pointer I blush to admit that I do not own a computer. What you see from me has ben forced via an elderly 'phone. Now I shall go hide my head in shame.

Comment: @user94874 Nothing to be ashamed of, don't let anyone make you feel that way. You've made an appearance here which has already required some tenacity.